# Controller in Backbone.js

Tags: model-view-controller, backbone.js

I'm new to Backbone.js. I have gone through the documentation. My question is
 where does the controller concept come into picture? In other words, what is a controller in Backbone.js?

I heard that the router is the controller. If so, why it is considered as a controller? Can we develop simple basic apps without the Router also? In that case what will be the controller?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

To clear things a little bit here. A Router is not a Controller, It's a way to define a client-side route map (similar to Rails's routes.rb). This helps routing client-side pages to certain actions/handlers. And that's different from a controller's job which is to provide a bit of orchestration between Models and Views. And there is actually more than one way to do this using Backbone. Quoting from [Backbone's documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-tim-toady):

> References between Models and Views can be handled several ways. Some
>   people like to have direct pointers, where views correspond 1:1 with
>   models (model.view and view.model). Others prefer to have intermediate
>   "controller" objects that orchestrate the creation and organization of
>   views into a hierarchy. Others still prefer the evented approach, and
>   always fire events instead of calling methods directly. All of these
>   styles work well.

This brings three different approaches to accomplish this. The first one is pretty straightforward which is to have the model object included as a property to the view.

The second one proposes including a third component that performs this role of orchestration. I believe this can be helpful in quite large and complex applications. For this I encourage you to look at [Chaplin](https://github.com/chaplinjs/chaplin), a sample application architecture using Backbone.js. The guys have done a great job in separating things out and also introduced the concept of a Controller into the architecture.

The last approach is suggesting using events to mark for actions and mediator to handle these actions. For this I encourage you to look into the mediator and Publish/Subscribe JavaScript patterns.

Answer (score 12):

Check out Addy Osmani`s article on MV* on the client:

http://addyosmani.com/blog/understanding-mvc-and-mvp-for-javascript-and-backbone-developers/

From the article:

> In Backbone, one shares the responsibility of a controller with both the Backbone.View and Backbone.Router.

and

> In this respect, contrary to what might be mentioned in the official documentation or in blog posts, Backbone is neither a truly MVC/MVP nor MVVM framework.

Answer (score 7):

It's more similar to how for example iOS Cocoa Touch framework works, you shouldn't think about it like a backend MVC, backbone team itself even never mentions MVC on their website to avoid confusion people often have when coming from backend MVCs. The View in backbone is  what's called in iOS a ViewController/AppController and usually your main AppController will be a View which sets the main wrapper for your application which usually you would also use as a global pub/sub system and controller for your main app logics.

Router is exactly what it say - it converts routes into set of params and passes them to the app controller to figure out what to do with them, what subview to load etc. (or if application is less sophisticated it can load/change the views straight from the router level) - It used to be called controller but it was renamed in (0.5 I believe?) to clear this confusion.

At least this is our approach - if you checked multiple tutorials in the wild you've probably seen that when it comes to Backbone there are as many approaches to this as many developers there are. And that's what is beautiful about Backbone! :)

Answer (score 3):

Usually I make my own controllers, and let the router do it's thing (catching routes, and pointing towards a controller action). These controllers are home made, just javascript objects with methods on them. They take the request from the router, collect the right data (collections, models...) and take the necessary view, combine them and pass the data into the view.

from there on it's backbone again.

however recently I came arcoss a 3rd party backbone plugin called [backboneMVC](https://github.com/chance-an/backbone-mvc). Have read it's documention, but have yet to try it out myself.

It aims to take over your router and make routes based on your controllers and actions you define with it.

Take a look at that library however I cannot promise anything because I have yet to build something with it myself.